# How can I filter posts according to their tags?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are my table structure:

```
// questions_and_answers
+----+---------------+------------------------+---------+---------+
| id |    subject    |           body         | related | deleted |
+----+---------------+------------------------+---------+---------+
| 1  | subject1      | question1 test         | NULL    | 0       |
| 2  |               | answer1                | 1       | 0       |
| 3  | subject2      | question2 test         | NULL    | 0       |
| 4  |               | answer2                | 3       | 1       |
| 5  |               | answer3   test         | 3       | 0       |
| 6  | subject3      | question3              | NULL    | 1       |
| 7  |               | answer4   test         | 6       | 0       |
+----+---------------+------------------------+---------+---------+
-- related column contains either NULL for questions or the id of its question for answers

// tags
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
| 1  | mysql  |
| 2  | php    |
+----+--------+

// pivot 
+-------------+--------+
| question_id | tag_id |
+-------------+--------+
| 1           | 1      |
| 3           | 1      |
| 3           | 2      |
| 6           | 1      |
+-------------+--------+
```

I need to search in the questions (an all its answers) that are tagged with specific tag. For example, this is **the expected result** for `[php]` tag and `test` entry:

```
| 3  | subject2      | question2 test         | NULL    | 0       |
| 5  |               | answer3   test         | 3       | 0       |
```

---

So firstly I need to filter posts according to tags. For `[php]` tag, this is the right filtering:

```
| 3  | subject2      | question2 test         | NULL    | 0       |
| 4  |               | answer2                | 3       | 1       |
| 5  |               | answer3   test         | 3       | 0       |
```

And then filter the result according to the entry. For `test` entry, this is the right filtering: *(which is the same as the expected result)*

```
| 3  | subject2      | question2 test         | NULL    | 0       |
| 5  |               | answer3   test         | 3       | 0       |
```

---

Here is my current query, It doesn't support tag-filtering. How can I add tag-filtering to it?

```
SELECT COALESCE(qa2.subject, qa.subject) subject,
       qa.body
FROM questions_and_answers qa
LEFT JOIN questions_and_answers qa2 ON qa.related = qa2.id
WHERE MATCH(qa.subject,qa.body) AGAINST (:entry)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:

```
select distinct COALESCE(T2.id,T1.id) question_id
    ,COALESCE(T2.subject,T1.subject) subject
    ,COALESCE(T2.body,T1.body) body 
    ,T4.name tagName
from (
  ##To get body and filter body contains [test]   
  select * from questions_and_answers
  where body like '%test%'
) T1
##To get tag and filter tagName [php] 
left join questions_and_answers T2 on T1.related = T2.id
left join pivot  T3 on T3.question_id  = COALESCE(T2.id,T1.id)
left join tags T4 on T4.id = T3.tag_id
where T4.name like '%php%'
```

**Result:**

```
| question_id |  subject |           body | tagName |
|-------------|----------|----------------|---------|
|           3 | subject2 | question2 test |     php |
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo Test Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d3c34/18/0)